# Numbering in Devanāgarī while using XeTeX

Tags: xetex, indic

I have been using XeTeX for typsetting Devanāgarī documents and it is going great. But I have encountered one issue, that whenever i use commands like \section, \begin{enumerate},\footnote or any command that generates numbering the numbering appears in the roman. Like
1,2,3 but I want to it in Devanāgarī like १, २, ३ ,४ ....
Any possible way/best practices to make this happen ?

PS: Once fixed, this could be used for other Indic Scripts too.

Comment: Look at [my answer on your earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari). There I discuss the solution to Devanagari numerals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better and easier solution is to use the package `polyglossia`:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
```

This should be enough to switch on Devanāgarī numerals. (Is Hindi the correct language? I’m guessing here. According to the documentation of `polyglossia` it has the correct numerals, at least.)

Comment: If numerals comes as १,२,३,४ in polyglossia. Hindi can be correct.

Comment: While using polyglossia, my compiler says ! LaTeX Error: File `polyglossia.sty' not found.

Comment: @Ujjwol: if the file isn’t found, you need to install that package from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/polyglossia/).

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own numbering style as follows:

```
\newcommand*\devanagari[1]{\expandafter\@devanagari\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\newcommand*\@devanagari[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or १\or २\or ३\or ४\or ५\or ६\or ७\or ८\or ९\fi}
```

Since this code uses the `@` character in commands, you need to put `\makeatletter` before this code if it’s not in a package file. And it’s best to put `\makeatother` after it, to switch the character code of `@` back to its default.

Then you can use this numbering style like any other (e.g. `\arabic` or `\roman`). For example, to set the footnote numbering, do the following:

```
\renewcommand*\thefootnote{\devanagari{footnote}}
```

And to change the first-level enumeration style, do:

```
\renewcommand*\theenumi{\devanagari{enumi}}
```

Comment: Just check what is wrong with the code below.

Comment: Check this code, it is not working. http://pastebin.com/g37g4GHp

Comment: @Ujjwol: you didn’t follow the second half of my posting! Just creating the `\devanagari` command won’t apply it in the text, you explicitly have to assign the enumeration style. Furthermore, better put these declarations into the header, before the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Ujjwol: Take a look at the other answer I wrote. That is a better way. Feel free to ignore my first answer.