# How can I type in Devnagari font using LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, languages, indic

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to learn it. It is very interesting. I have to type a lot of documents that contain Devnagari text, more precisely Nepali Language. How can I type it using LaTeX, so that I could make beautiful document in my own language?

Comment: I recommend using XeTeX. Have a look at: [Getting Started to XeTeX for Devanagari](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari).

Comment: Please let us know by a comment if the answers in the linked question solved your question too. We would close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: Still looking for the solution - it would have been nice if we could natively write Nepali in tex studio without going to Sanskrit and translate it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Charles Wikner's [Sanskrit](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/sanskrit/) package, available from CTAN. With this package, you would enter transliterated text and it would be converted into Devanagari (it does ligatures properly if I remember correctly).

The documentation is in the file sktdoc.ps.

*edit*: in Debian and Ubuntu, the same package used to be available with the name "`latex-sanskrit`", but was removed from the archives (I  don't know the reason)

Comment: Stefan Kottwitz's answer (xelatex) in the comments above is better - you can type directly in Devanagari and don't have to do intermediate transliteration through the Latin script.

Comment: Some people actually need to type the transliteration -- it's used by western Sanskrit scholars, for example.

Comment: Of course, transliteration would be better for western Sanskrit scholars. But here the question refers to "my own language", so I am assuming typing directly in Devanagari would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

`babel` provides partial support for Nepali in XeTeX and LuaTeX, but you may need to supply the captions yourself. An example for LuaTeX is (I've used a Windows font, but you can select another font of your choice):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nepali, provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide[mapdigits]{nepali}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Sanskrit Text}

\setlocalecaption{nepali}{chapter}{अध्याय}

\begin{document}

\chapter{नेपाल}

नेपाल (आधिकारिक नाम: सङ्घीय लोकतान्त्रिक गणतन्त्र नेपाल) दक्षिण एशियाली
भूपरिवेष्ठित हिमाली राष्ट्र हो। नेपालको पूर्वी सीमाना मेची नदी देखि
पश्चिमी सीमाना महाकाली नदीसम्मको औसत लम्बाइ ८८५ किलोमिटर छ।

\end{document}
```

[image: LuaTeX Nepali]