# How to use tikz package with devanagari, in miktex 2.8

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to use `tikz` graphics with my PDF file, written in MiKTeX 2.8 LaTeX.

When I write `\usepackage{tikz}` with `\usepackage{devanagari}`, LaTeX produces an error

```
l.264
      catcode '\"=12
```

Answer (score 4):

The loading order is important: load `tikz` before `devanagari`, not the other way round. This example works with pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
Here is devanagari:
{\dn calo devanagarI me likhate hai}
\end{document}
```

If you change the order of `tikz` and `devanagari` in this example, you would get the mentioned error

```
l.264   
       \catcode`\"=12
```

Btw. XeLaTeX is useful for writing Devanagari, perhaps have look at

- [Getting Started to Xetex for Devangari](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari)