# why there is no direct typesetting in LaTeX for other than english language?

Tags: languages

While using LaTeX I always wondered, why it is necessary to typeset any language other than english, like indic (devnagari) first in english as `.dn` file and then use some translator to translate it in indic syllab to generate `.tex` file. then compile, and then get the final pdf output...

For english just by keying the english is enough and for other languages latex uses, "do not use latex hereafter approach" by using some translation mechanism...

Is it possible for LaTeX developers to make use of other languages as easy as using English in latex... If so please do it or atleast ask some intelligent members of community to develope like that...

Comment: Isn't it possible to write the tex file in unicode and compile it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: why would you need to translate it? You can just type it normally and use UTF-8 input encoding.

Comment: Look for example at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari

Comment: the real answer to your question is that the "original" tex (late 1970s) was very restricted, and translation was the best way forward.  some restrictions were removed with tex version 3, but still not enough for "native" devanagari (or afaik any other indic font).  recent developments have changed all that, with their capability of using unicode input.

Answer (score 8):

Almost ten years have passed since this question and things have radically changed, thanks to `xetex` and `luatex`, and the latest developments in LaTeX itself. Here is an example combining Arabic, Bengali, Greek and Japanese with `babel` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[japanese]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{IPAexMincho}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\startlocale}[1]{%
  \selectlanguage{#1}%
  \section{\foreignlanguage{nil}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\startlocale{arabic}

يولد جميع الناس أحرارًا متساوين في الكرامة والحقوق. وقد وهبوا عقلاً وضميرًا وعليهم أن يعامل بعضهم بعضًا بروح الإخاء.

\startlocale{bengali}

সমস্ত মানুষ স্বাধীনভাবে সমান মর্যাদা এবং অধিকার নিয়ে জন্মগ্রহণ করে। তাঁদের বিবেক এবং বুদ্ধি আছে; সুতরাং সকলেরই একে অপরের প্রতি ভ্রাতৃত্বসুলভ মনোভাব নিয়ে আচরণ করা উচিৎ।

\startlocale{greek}

Όλοι οι άνθρωποι γεννιούνται ελεύθεροι και ίσοι στην αξιοπρέπεια και τα δικαιώματα. Είναι προικισμένοι με λογική και συνείδηση, και οφείλουν να συμπεριφέρονται μεταξύ τους με πνεύμα αδελφοσύνης.

\startlocale{japanese}

すべての人間は、生れながらにして自由であり、かつ、尊厳と権利とについて平等である。人間は、理性と良心とを授けられており、互いに同胞の精神をもって行動しなければならない。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is possible to compile tex documents containing davanagari characters.

I have not tried compiling with latex but xelatex compiles such documents without any problem.

Comment: Maybe an example could shed more light on the matter.