# Hindi characters in PDF file

Tags: fonts, languages

Would you please provide me with a simple example of how to use pdfLaTeX (under MiKTeX) to generate a PDF file with Hindi Characters on it?

Comment: I am using MikTek in Windows

Comment: You can try the [`devanagari`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/devanagari/) package. Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari

Comment: SUGGESTED EDIT BY HECTOR LAKE: Thank you for your comment. I tried it but I got "The font Nukula not found" Any additional ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: As it stands this looks too broad: at least some idea of what you've tried and where the issues are is really needed.