# Using Tibetan and Devanagari Unicode Script in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am quite new to LaTeX and I am trying to make a document with both Tibetan and Devanagari script.  I know one can use XeLaTeX to use different Unicode scripts directly in your code, but for whatever reason, all I get when I compile is question marks where the script should be.  What do I need to change to get this to work properly?  I have looked in many manuals and searched this site but I haven't seen an explanation of this.  I am using a Mac.  Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}

བོད་ཡིག་ཡང་ཡོང་གི་ཡོད་མ་རེད།

शारदा शारदाम्भोजवदना वदनाम्बुजे।
सर्वदा सर्वदास्माकं संनिधिं संनिधिं क्रियात्।।

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the log? it appears to work for me (but I can not read the script) I put an image here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20432324#20432324

Comment: @David I don't either get any error, but the output is not the one one expects. See the previous question of the OP http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229492/27635.

Comment: @karlkoeller isn't this question an exact duplicate?

Comment: @David Probably, but the OP hasn't got an anwer yet...

Comment: yes but re-asking the same question while waiting for an answer is the wrong thing. I'll vote to close this one.