# Switching between Devanagari script and italicized Roman script

Tags: fonts, indic

I am making a document in which I would like have text in Devanagari script and italicized Roman script interspersed amongst one another.  If my Devanagari font had an italicized Roman font, I would use that, but it doesn't have one.  So, outside of finding a Devanagari font that includes italicized Roman script, which I haven't been able to do, I will have to switch every few words between fonts, which isn't very practical.  Is there an easier way to switch between a Devanagari script and another Roman font whose italicized script I can use?

Comment: I assume you've seen [this answer to Getting Started to Xetex for Devangari?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2579/3345). If your document is largely Devangari with only some English or other language, you can make a short macro like `\eng` to switch to the Roman font.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this is working.  Where can I find more info on how this command `\newcommand\eng[1]{\textenglish{#1}}` works?  I just copy-pasted it into my document, I don't know what `[1]` means, for example.

Comment: Mandatory argument, position 1. It's whatever is between the first set of braces as in `\eng{some text}`