# Write Bhagavad Gita Sanskrit verse in Devanagari XeLaTex

Tags: fonts, languages, indic

I am looking to write the following famous verse of Srimad Bhagavad Gita in  Devanagari using XeLaTex:

Karmanye vadhikaraste Ma Phaleshu Kadachana । Ma Karmaphalaheturbhurma Te Sangostvakarmani ।।

I have no idea of how to transcribe English to Devanagari fonts. Thank you.

Comment: "I have no idea of how to transcribe English to Devanagari fonts. Thank you." Well that really has nothing to do with TeX-LaTeX I'm afraid but what the hey

Comment: कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन।
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि॥४७॥

Karmaṇy evādhikāras te mā phaleṣu kadācana;
Mā karmaphalahetur bhūr mā te saṅgo'stv akarmaṇi.

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript) or [this](http://shreevatsa.appspot.com/sanskrit/transliterate.html) to transliterate into Devanagari script, and you need to have installed a font that supports Devanagari (e.g. Noto Sans Devanagari or Sanskrit 2003 or Chandas), then you can use the [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/getting-started-to-xetex-for-devangari/2578#2578).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use the `fontspec` package to use a suitable Devanagari Unicode font.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\SA}[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003}
```

It is then simply a matter of putting in the Devanagari. The way you do that is really off-topic here! I used a Devanagari keyboard layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\SA}[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003}

\begin{document}

{\SA कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन~। \\
  मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि~॥~४७~॥}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `~`s in the Sanskrit are just non-breaking spaces to make sure that no line is broken before the daṇḍa or the double daṇḍas or anything.