# Section numbering in Devanagari in polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

Am using Polyglossia to generate Sanskrit documents. Simple document (article). but with small sections. The section numbers generated are in arabic font and not in Devanagari. How to solve this?

Comment: you have not shown what you did or what error you got but there are examples on site showing section numbering eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2579/1090

Comment: Sorry!! Here is a small working example

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\begin{document}
\begin{sanskrit}
\section{विभक्तिः}
उदाहरणानि
\section{समासः}
उदाहरणानि
\end{sanskrit}
\end{document}

The examples compiles well. The section number is, however, arabic and not in Devanagari